# WPF Datagrid Grouping using a parent object as the expander header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using WPF Datagrid to group an observable collection by Parent. I have been following the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control) and other examples showing a parent child relationship. So far I have the following:

[image]

And I want to get something like this:

[image]

Where the Header of a group is just a row as well but still able to collapse/expand child rows. I have tried to make a sub-datagrid without luck. So the underlying type of my collection looks something like this:

```
public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    // memebers
    ...

    public string ProjectName
    {
        get { return this.m_ProjectName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.m_ProjectName)
            {
                this.m_ProjectName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProjectName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string TaskName
    {
        get { return this.m_TaskName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.m_TaskName)
            {
                this.m_TaskName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TaskName");
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime DueDate
    {
        get { return this.m_DueDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.m_DueDate)
            {
                this.m_DueDate = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DueDate");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Complete
    {
        get { return this.m_Complete; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.m_Complete)
            {
                this.m_Complete = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Complete");
            }
        }
    }

    public Task Parent
    {
        get { return m_Parent; }
        set
        {
            m_Parent = value;
        }
    }
```

So my object type can either by a child or parent, where a child has a reference to its parent. So I am grouping by parent, I just haven't figured out how to make the expandable group headers rows of the same type. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              ColumnWidth="*"
              RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#FF112255" BorderBrush="#FF002255" Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource completeConverter}}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Width="Auto"/>

                                            </DockPanel>
                                            <!--<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" 
                                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsParentTasks}}"
                                                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                                                          ColumnWidth="*"
                                                          RowHeaderWidth="0"
                                                          HeadersVisibility="None" >
                                                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEEEEEE" />
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF112255" />
                                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                                </DataGrid>-->
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't think you can actually do it properly with a `DataGrid`. Your group header is not really part of the object collection. So if you want to design it, you'll have to do it with a `Grid` or something close. If you really want to have a Parent/Childs logic, then you should think about a `Treeview`.

Comment: @arias_JC I have the exact same usecase right now, did you get this sorted? if yes, please answer your own question here on SO